# Systemverilog to Verilog translation

Tags: verilog, conversion, system-verilog

I have a code block (multiple files) in Systemverilog. I am using the Xilinx tool flow that does not understand SystemVerilog (an old part). Is there a tool (or a rule book) I can use to convert the SystemVerilog to standard Verilog-2001 code ?

Comment: Which SystemVerilog constructs need to be converted? Examples are: types (logic, bit), classes, interfaces, packages, randomization, etc.

Comment: I am looking to convert only the synthesizable parts of the code. Logic, Bit and packages should be sufficient

Answer (score 10):

Not aware of any tool that will automatically do the conversion. You could do it by hand or write your own script. Here is a list of common SystemVerilog to Verilog-2001 (or vice-versa)

- Easy conversions:

  - `always_comb` --> `always @*`
  - `always_latch` --> `always @*`, may want to add a synthesis directive for latch
  - `always_ff` --> `always`
  - `int` --> `integer` *or* `reg signed [31:0]`
  - `shortint` --> `reg signed [15:0]`
  - `longint` --> `time` *or* `reg signed [63:0]`
  - `bit`/`logic` --> `reg`
  - `byte` --> `reg [7:0]`
  - `unique` --> remove and add synthesis directives `full_case parallel_case`
  - `priority` --> remove and add synthesis directives `full_case`
- More challenging conversions:

  - `var = '0;` --> `var = {PARAM_VAR_BITS{1'b0}};`
  - `'1`/`'X`/`'Z` --> same as `'0` and substitute all `0` with `1`/`X`/`Z` respectively
  - `function void` --> if not called by any other function then `task` else `function reg` any calls should assign a dummy bit.
  - `interface` --> *either* add each net to the respective module port list ***or*** create `` `include `` files.
  - `enum` --> make each item a `parameter`, make the variable of packed array (aka IEEE 1364 vector) of `reg`
  - `struct` --> *either* separate out each item ***or*** make one bus with `parameters` as position keys
  - `union packed` --> same as `struct` plus some intelligent bus connections (ex: `{dest_0[3:0],dest_1,...,dest_n[1:0]}={src_0,src_1[1:0]...,src_n[9:0]}` )

Answer (score 4):

I recently released an open source tool for converting SystemVerilog to Verilog. It covers many of the differences highlighted by the other answer. Check it out at https://github.com/zachjs/sv2v.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but just to share a solution I used. Not a great one, but here it is. Use RTL Compiler with synthesize -to_generic. That creates a Verilog compatible netlist. This isn't perfect b/c it also implements the flip-flop logic in terms that aren't exactly optimal for Xilinx's tools.